# Jython, stop script execution from inside of Java code

Tags: java, multithreading, jython, jython-2.7

I'm using Jython as a scripting engine in my Java app. 
I can run any Jython script from my Java app by calling pi.execfile(script_name). But the problem is that I also need a way to stop script execution manually from Java code. How can I stop it without modifying Jython script?

I'm running a script in a separate thread, so tried to interrupt it via 
scriptRunningThread.interrupt(); and catch InterrupredException, but the thread just suspend and hang... Newly created threads will be hang too

Another way - to share a common object and make Jython script to check if user wants to quit.

The 3rd way is to run a separate process (console mode of my app) and kill it when ever STOP button being pressed. But I don't like this solution...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is your second idea:  to have the Jython script check for a termination flag and exit cleanly if the flag is set.

If you wanted to terminate the thread from another thread, you could call Thread.stop(), but that is generally a bad idea since it could cause your entire application to hang or otherwise misbehave in certain circumstances.

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to force user to add that check statement